# Does console.log treat 'this' differently?

Tags: javascript, console.log

Why does the following statement:

```
(function(){ console.log(this); }).apply(String("hello"));
```

display the following output

```
String {0: "h", 1: "e", 2: "l", 3: "l", 4: "o", length: 5}
```

and not a simple:

```
hello
```

Is this behavior built-in to the interpreter or is there a way to detect the type of reference passed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that you get an object and not a string as the output of your function is that by default javascript 'this' object is always forced to be an object.

If you however use javascript in a strict format with 'use strict' then this is disabled and you can get the result that you would expect.

```
// wrapped in a function to allow copy paste into console
(function() {
   'use strict';

   (function(){ console.log(this); }).apply(String("hello")); 
})();
```

A more thorough explanation about 'strict mode' and why it removes the boxing of this into an object can be found on the mozilla site [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript)

Comment: How does the string get forced/promoted to be an object? Is there something I can do manually (in JS code) to get the same effect? Any other interesting side effects (i.e. cases where this object-string does not behave like you would expect a string to)?

Comment: Strings, Numbers etc are actually always objects in JavaScript. They have properties for example like the ones seen above. If you want a String object (that looks like an object when logged) from the beginning then use the 'new' keyword (new String("hello");)
As for behaviour - it should behave like any other javascript string except for the logging (although I am not 100% confident on this part)

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, `this` can't be a primitive type; you would need to use [`.valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) to fetch the primitive value, i.e.:

```
(function(){ console.log(this.valueOf()); }).apply(String("hello"));
```

Or use `'use strict';` like DeadAlready mentioned in his answer.